# What is the best practices to show in URL query for array search?

Tags: php, arrays, url

Let's say I want to create a search form & using [chosen jQuery](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) **multiple select**

I'll use `$_GET` to keep the query for pagination. Example my select form

```
<select name="q[]" data-placeholder="Please Select" multiple>
   <optgroup label="Choose a Location">
   <option value="l_1">Location A</option> 
   <option value="l_2">Location A</option> 
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Choose a Type">
   <option value="t_1">Type A</option> 
   <option value="t_2">Type B</option> 
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Choose a Room">
   <option value="r_1">Room A</option> 
   <option value="r_2">Room B</option> 
   </optgroup>   
</select>
```

The URL query `http:/domain.com/search/?q[]=l_1&q[]=t_1&q[]=t_2&q[]=r_1&q[]=r_2`

There have a another option how should the URL will looks like?

Comment: You appear to have three different questions there. Why are you using a single input? This looks like a job for three radio groups, not one select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There have a another option how should the URL will looks like?

No. The generated URL will be field_name=value, and that will be duplicated for each value.

This is how forms work. Browsers know how to generate them. Server side form data parsers know how to process them.

URLs are tools. They don't need to be works of art. Especially when they are being generated from user input.

Comment: I *think* you are asking "If I use jQuery's `form.serialize()` method, will that work?". If so, then yes, it will generate the same URI as a normal form submission.

Answer (score 0):

GET will use the name of your element, which is p[]. If you don't like the square brackets, take them out.

```
search/?q=l_1&q=l_2
```

You can, if desired, use [Friendly URL Rewriting](http://zenverse.net/seo-friendly-urls-with-htaccess/) to make your links look more pleasing (and better for your SEO performance). I'm not certain how useful that'll be on a search page...

Comment: The `[]` turn the GET variable into an array (at least in PHP), if you remove them, you will only get the value of the last `q` value (again, at least in PHP).